# Unable to boot Beaglebone Green with Debian 7.8

Tags: debian, boot, beagleboneblack

I'm unable to boot my `Beaglebone green` from SD card having `Debian 7.8` Image. Also I can't install Debian 7.8 into `eMMC`. There is no problem with `Debian 8.4`. Problem is not with SD card as I have tested same SD card with `Beagelbone Black` and I'm able to boot with that.

This happens only with `Beaglebone Green` and not with `Beaglebone Black`. Can anyone suggest a way to get it done.